# Printing byte array containing EBCDIC values doesnt give expected value

Tags: java, string, ebcdic

I created a string converted got a  byte array using EBCDIC encoding from it. When I printed the array the value of H it is not the same found in EBCDIC chart.

**Expected output**

EBCDIC Value for "H"-->200 as per link [EBCDIC 1047 chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_1047)

**Actual output**

EBCDIC Value for "H"-->[-56]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String str = "H";
    byte[] b1 = new byte[10];
    b1 = str.getBytes("Cp1047");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b1));

    for (byte b : b1) {
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    b1 = str.getBytes("UTF-16");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b1));

    b1 = str.getBytes();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b1));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your loop

```
for (byte b : b1)
   System.out.println(b);
```

Java is sign extending b (a byte) when it promotes it to an integer which results in the value of `0xFFFFFFC8` being printed.  `0xFFFFFFC8` is the two's complement representation of the signed number -56.  See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). You can prevent the sign extension by doing this:

```
for (byte b  :b1)
  System.out.println(b & 0xFF);
```

This will cause the value `0xC8` (200 in decimal) to get printed.